# Check if product attribute exist/got value admin

Tags: php, admin, adminhtml, product-attribute, php-7

I want to edit the template `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml`

This so that I can add my own custom attribute to the sales order.
Therefore I created a line, that does work perfect for orders with products that still exists.

But when the order contains products that has been removed, the sales order does not load and the page breaks.

How can I change my line, so that it checks if the attribute value exists (or if the product still exists)?

CODE;

```
<?php $product_dpn = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('dpn'));
$product_mpn = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('mpn')); ?>

<div><?php if ($product_dpn->getDpn()): echo $product_dpn->getDpn(); endif; ?></div>
<div><?php if ($product_mpn->getMpn()): echo $product_mpn->getMpn(); endif; ?></div>
```

Comment: products that has been removed means ? from order or store ?

Comment: @KeyurShah Sorry, products that has been removed from store. So it can not find that product attribute and it breaks the page. So I need a if rule, that checks if the product exists or the value exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put some condition like check product is exist or not in store

```
 <?php
       if(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($_item->getSku())) {
 ?>
    <?php $product_dpn = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('dpn'));
    $product_mpn = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('mpn')); ?>

    <div><?php if ($product_dpn->getDpn()): echo $product_dpn->getDpn(); endif; ?></div>
    <div><?php if ($product_mpn->getMpn()): echo $product_mpn->getMpn(); endif; ?></div>
     <?php
 }    
     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does also remove the code for products that do exists. So it remove the code in all orders.

Comment: just updated the answer please check @HenkZ